# Selenium fails to detect elements in ms teams (web) call interface

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-teams, selenium-ide

Selenium is not detecting elements in the microsoft teams (web) calling interface (after call has connected).  For example:

```
'Store xpath count' action with xpath=\\profile-picture
```

Returns zero entries (an explicit wait was used beforehand to ensure page was fully loaded)

The exact same xpath, executed using chrome's developer tools, returned 4 entries.

Similar results are obtained for other actions, and other elements (including those selected using the selenium ide's locator picker).

Is there something that I am missing here that is preventing me from picking up these elements?

The page does not appear to have any iframes (which could cause this behaviour).

Requested code trial from selenium IDE side file (NB requires logged-on teams instance without the other popups & phone number to test):

```
{
  "id": "d0ff19e7-9ada-4a49-96f3-f43649709cff",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "TeamsTest",
  "url": "",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "e9060b4d-c8d0-4ad4-972c-029bc4403b4c",
    "name": "Untitled",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "cdd5f51d-31b9-465a-9d64-c7c6b8ad19a9",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "/_#/calls/saved-calls",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "094ae461-1b76-442d-822f-36c844913720",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "setWindowSize",
      "target": "1366x698",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "20dd83d6-d0e3-4ccf-8ae7-55a90acf1791",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "waitForElementPresent",
      "target": "xpath=//iframe[starts-with(@id,'experience-container')]",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "30000"
    }, {
      "id": "6600e22d-8d34-4aee-86d1-78d79929b34a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "selectFrame",
      "target": "index=0",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "27542c6e-b6f5-4f53-a54e-4a51708f6d1a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "type",
      "target": "id=people-picker-input",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "<phone number>"
    }, {
      "id": "49de70ea-857e-46b3-aa7f-bd6a5da78d43",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "xpath=//button[contains(.'Call')]",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "4b20b541-c56c-44ba-a4ad-fbe3c3abec50",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "pause",
      "target": "10000",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "6aa3673a-6b4f-4543-aea1-5b370f83942f",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "storeXpathCount",
      "target": "xpath=//profile-picture",
      "targets": [],
      "value": "out"
    }, {
      "id": "2eba7802-2b98-4765-9fe7-cc664803af4d",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "echo",
      "target": "${out}",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "6b30048a-ecf9-4c60-bc27-cde0df580edd",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["e9060b4d-c8d0-4ad4-972c-029bc4403b4c"]
  }],
  "urls": [],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Comment: Post code trials.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I've added an example side file code (<phone number> will have to be substituted in the code).

Comment: @Prophet That is the contents of the .side file that is loaded by the selenium IDE on chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en).  That is what I've been executing the tests from, hence the 'selenium-ide' tag.  As far as I am aware, the only other code involved is that of the IDE itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that an iframe was entered when setting up the call, but a switch back to the default frame was not performed.  Once the appropriate command to swap back to the default context was issued, the problem was resolved.